# NavigationStack's navigationDestination in Xcode beta unable to navigate

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I am still new to SwiftUI framework I am learning with HackingWithSwift for NavigationStack. I followed all the steps just one difference is my result of code. I ran without any error just like in video however I could not navigate to my Detail destination.

```
  struct ContentView: View {
   var destinations = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
   var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        List(destinations, id: \.self) { i in
            NavigationLink(value: i) {
                Label("Row \(i)", systemImage: "\(i).circle")
            }
        }
        .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { i in
            Text("Detail \(i)")
        }
        .navigationTitle("Navigation")
     }
   }
  }
```

My simulator show a List of Rows with Labels but I am unable to navigate.
Could this by chance a bug because this is still new. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your `List` data is an array of `String`, but the `.navigationDestination` value type is `Int`.

To fix your problem, modify the data type of .navigationDestination like below:

```
.navigationDestination(for: String.self) { I in //modify here
        Text("Detail \(i)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is special `List` (and `ForEach`) syntax for a static array of `Int`, here it is:

```
struct NavTestView: View {

  //let destinations = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

  var body: some View {
   NavigationStack {
       List(1..<10) { i in
           NavigationLink(value: i) {
               Label("Row \(i)", systemImage: "\(i).circle")
           }
       }
       .navigationDestination(for: Int.self) { i in
           Text("Detail \(i)")
       }
       .navigationTitle("Navigation")
    }
  }
 }
```

If you move on to requiring a dynamic array, i.e. you add or remove items, you really shouldn't misuse the API with the `id:\.self` hack or it'll crash, you need to migrate to an array of struct that contains a property that is a unique identifier, even better conform the struct to [`Identifiable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/identifiable) that provides an `id` property for `List`/`ForEach` to use automatically, e.g.

```
struct ListItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: Int
}
```